# Can't understand something about the convolutional networks gradient in TensorFlow

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

[Here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_grad_ops.cc#L171) is the description about convolutional networks gradient in TensorFlow.

I don't know the meaning of `A' = a' * X^t`. I know `A'` stand for the  backprops. And `^t` is the Latex notation.

But `t` is undefined. So the point is the meaning of `X^t`

Comment: I guess it's transposed

Comment: Because `A'` and `a'` are the backprops , so I think `X^t` represent the weight somehow.

Comment: It means transposed, but this seems a bit off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

^t means "superscript t", which is a shorthand for "transposed".